# REDIS EXISTS with PHP

Tags: php, redis, exists

I have multiple keys that have the same name except for one word `(user.delete.id`, `user.add.id`, `user.update.id`... etc). I want to delete a certain key if any of those keys exist. So I was wondering if it's possible to do something like the following PHP:

In User class

```
$cachekey = 'user.'
```

In another class

```
$redis->exists(User::$cachekey.'*.'.$id)
```

will using the asterisk symbol work?

Comment: you can only get keys using KEYS * .id. * but you cannot delete or use EXIST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Vigikaran your solution cannot be applied to commands like EXISTS.

**Update: improved solution**

An idiomatic solution to your problem would be to use a hash to store the values.

When you set a value for user.add.id:

```
HSET user.id add somevalue
```

I used raw Redis commands, but it should translate literaly in PHP (the exact syntax may vary according to the driver you are using).

Please note I changed the name of the key: it's user.id in my example. the variable part of your keys ('add', 'delete'...) becomes a field name in my solution.

If you want to delete a key, use HDEL

```
HDEL user.id add
```

Then to test the existence of at least one key, just use EXISTS:

```
EXISTS user.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into using a hash to store my values